# How to get correct length of a string containing emojis in C#

Tags: c#, .net

The [English-flag-emoji](https://emojipedia.org/flag-for-england/) consists 14 bytes of data, that when combined will render one single character - .

If I have code that looks like this:

```
var test = "\ud83c\udff4\udb40\udc67\udb40\udc62\udb40\udc65\udb40\udc6e\udb40\udc67\udb40\udc7f";

Console.WriteLine(test);
Console.WriteLine(test.Length);
```

It will print the character, and the number `14`. I somehow want it to return `1`. While searching the interwebs for an answer, I found this solution:

```
var stringInfo = new System.Globalization.StringInfo(test);
Console.WriteLine(stringInfo.LengthInTextElements);
```

The problem is, it instead prints `7`. I guess it interpret it as double-byte unicode and just gives me half of the byte-length. See this [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/au0GyX) for a working example.

How can I get the number of glyphs that a string will be represented as?

Here is a similar test written in Swift, running in XCode on OSX, and it clearly is working just as I want, but I need it in C#.

[image: Swift playground]

Comment: If you replace your `test` initialization code with `var test = Char.ConvertFromUtf32(0x1F3F4).ToString();`, the expected length is displayed. Maybe you have some extra characters in there or something?

Comment: 0x1F3F4 isn't the same emoji, it's a plain black flag. The emoji I have in my example is the flag of England, https://emojipedia.org/flag-for-england/, and it needs all bytes to render that exact flag. On the computer, in the browser, they will render the same flag, but on iOS or Android, you will see the English flag.

Comment: From what I can determine, it's not possible to know that the 7 code points is displayed as a single "character". I found [this article](https://manishearth.github.io/blog/2017/01/14/stop-ascribing-meaning-to-unicode-code-points/) pretty enlightening.

Comment: Very interesting indeed, and a bit sad :)

Comment: This question has no happy answer.  Display text length is a very strong implementation detail of the OS text renderer engine.  On Windows there are many of them, the inevitable consequence of keeping decades old programs still working on new OS releases.   Something that Apple never worried much about.  Which one you get largely depends on the specific type of project you create.  They all have a way to measure displayed text length, but don't always produce the same result.  In a console mode app you got in fact the correct result, a console can't display emoji at all :)

Comment: you might be able to do it with a regex like this one: https://github.com/mathiasbynens/emoji-regex
By e.g. counting emojis found replacing them and then count the rest.

Comment: Problem is that the text can contain anything, not just emojis, and I want to get the same count that Swift is giving me. But @hans-passant might be correct, there is no happy answer :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may read a document here: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1pC7N32TnmDr2xzFW4HscA1DyAPPZnwILUH2_03UL6Jo/preview

Based on that, here's something that seems to work:
install NuGet packages:

- https://www.nuget.org/packages/icu.net/
- https://www.nuget.org/packages/Icu4c.Win.Full.Bin/
- https://www.nuget.org/packages/Icu4c.Win.Full.Lib/

and try this code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Icu.Wrapper.Init();
        var test = new string[]
        {
            "\ud83c\udff4\udb40\udc67\udb40\udc62\udb40\udc65\udb40\udc6e\udb40\udc67\udb40\udc7f",
            "\U0001F3F4\U000E0067\U000E0062\U000E0065\U000E006E\U000E0067\U000E007F",
            "e\u0301",
            "\U0001F468\U0001F3FF", 
        };

        foreach (var t in test)
        {
            var len = GetLen(t);
            Console.WriteLine(len);
        }
    }

    static int GetLen(string test)
    {
        var ci = Icu.BreakIterator.CreateCharacterInstance(new Icu.Locale("en_US"));
        ci.SetText(test);
        int len = 0;
        while (ci.MoveNext() != Icu.BreakIterator.DONE)
        {
            len++;
        }
        return len;
    }
}
```

Windows console cannot display these emojis, but you can inspect them in the watch or Immediate Window in Visual Studio.

HTH, Tom

Comment: Wow, it works perfectly! I just tried it with a database of about 2500 emojis, and they are all calculated as length 1. It also works perfectly to calculate the length of strings that contain emojis as a part of them. Thanx!

Answer (score 4):

In .NET 5 just use `StringInfo.LengthInTextElements`. This method in previous versions of .NET has wrong behavior on these emojis. You may take a look at this [blog](https://www.meziantou.net/how-to-correctly-count-the-number-of-characters-of-a-string.htm).

In my C# Interactive (.NET Core mode), I get this result:

```cs
> Environment.Version
[5.0.7]
> var stringInfo = new System.Globalization.StringInfo("");
. Console.WriteLine(stringInfo.LengthInTextElements);
1
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It would be better if you show an example of the implementation with your answer.

Comment: @DJ Thanks, I've updated the answer with an example.

Answer (score 2):

From your link:

> The England emoji is a sequence of the Waving Black Flag,  Tag Latin Small Letter G,  Tag Latin Small Letter B,  Tag Latin Small Letter E,  Tag Latin Small Letter N,  Tag Latin Small Letter G and  Cancel Tag emojis

These are 7 unicode characters, so the answer 7 is correct. The rules for displaying unicode characters are complicated. On some systems it will display the Flag for England, on my system it doesn't.

You can try the [ScriptItemize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/Usp10/nf-usp10-scriptitemize) function or the [GetGlyphIndicesW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-getglyphindicesw) function to do the counting for you.

Comment: It is true that there are 7 Unicode characters, but that is not a "proof" `7` should be the output. For example `(new System.Globalization.StringInfo("e\u0301")).LengthInTextElements` gives `1` even though `"e\u0301"` is _two_ Unicode characters. However, the two characters combine to one glyph which is equivalent to `é`.

Answer (score 0):

Long comment (maybe not really an answer).

The sequence `"\ud83c\udff4\udb40\udc67\udb40\udc62\udb40\udc65\udb40\udc6e\udb40\udc67\udb40\udc7f"` is a quite new Unicode standard, see for example [Wikipedia: Tags (Unicode block)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tags_(Unicode_block)). This is not yet supported in .NET (maybe it will never be).

Write your own method that supports it.

By the way, instead of writing:

```
"\ud83c\udff4\udb40\udc67\udb40\udc62\udb40\udc65\udb40\udc6e\udb40\udc67\udb40\udc7f"
```

it is more clear, in my opinion, to write:

```
"\U0001F3F4\U000E0067\U000E0062\U000E0065\U000E006E\U000E0067\U000E007F"
```

It is the same string, of course.

If your source code file is in an encoding the supports Unicode, you can also use:

```
""
```

of course.