# Assess if a c# string is a single Emoji OR an Emoji ZWJ Sequence?

Tags: c#, emoji

What would be a way to tell if a c# `string` is a single Emoji, or a valid Emoji ZWJ Sequences?

I would like to basically be able to find any Emoji from the official unicode list, http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr51/tr51-15.html#emoji_data

I don't seem to find a nuget package for this, and most SO questions don't seem to be *easily* applicable to my case (i.e. [Is there a way to check if a string in JS is one single emoji?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58942139/is-there-a-way-to-check-if-a-string-in-js-is-one-single-emoji) )

Comment: Store all the emoji char values in a HashSet<char>, then look for matches in your text. Hopefully, it would not be a huge string, but more like a comment type of thing.

Comment: That sounds like a real pain to maintain, but I guess that would work.

Comment: "pain to maintain": just download the lists from the link in your question.

Comment: That works for today, but requires special attention for later updates of the document.

Comment: Perhaps this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51502486/how-to-get-correct-length-of-a-string-containing-emojis-in-c-sharp/51644186#51644186) could help

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using Unicode regex, which are partially implemented in .NET.
Using this question ([C# - Regular expression to find a surrogate pair of a unicode codepoint from any string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55082644/c-sharp-regular-expression-to-find-a-surrogate-pair-of-a-unicode-codepoint-fro)), I came up with the following.

Regex

```cs
//Returns the Emoji
@"([\uD800-\uDBFF][\uDC00-\uDFFF]\p{M}*){1,5}|\p{So}"

//Returns true if the string is a single Emoji
@"^(?>(?>[\uD800-\uDBFF][\uDC00-\uDFFF]\p{M}*){1,5}|\p{So})$"
```

Tests

```cs
    public class EmojiTests
    {
        private static readonly Regex IsEmoji = new Regex(@"^(?>(?>[\uD800-\uDBFF][\uDC00-\uDFFF]\p{M}*){1,5}|\p{So})$", RegexOptions.Compiled);

        [Theory]
        [InlineData("⭐")]
        [InlineData("")]
        [InlineData("")]
        [InlineData("")]
        [InlineData("")]
        [InlineData("")]//pinched fingers, coming soon :p
        public void ValidEmojiCases(string input)
        {
            Assert.Matches(IsEmoji, input);
        }

        [Theory]
        [InlineData("")]
        [InlineData(":p")]
        [InlineData("a")]
        [InlineData("<")]
        [InlineData("⭐⭐")]
        [InlineData("a")]
        [InlineData("‼️")]
        [InlineData("↔️")]
        public void InvalidEmojiCases(string input)
        {
            Assert.DoesNotMatch(IsEmoji, input);
        }
    }
```

It is not perfect (i.e. returns true for "™️", false for "◻️"), but that will do.